# Column names when cross joining in MDX

Tags: reporting-services, mdx

I am applying a crossjoin to get the columns from MDX:

```
    SELECT { [Measures].[Balance] } ON 0,
NonEmpty ( {[Sources].[Sources].children*[AccountType].[Description].children}) ON 1
```

This however gives me the following:

```
|____|___________| Balance |
| XY | something | 12335435|
```

The result in its self is correct, but I need to name the two first columns so I can use the data in an RS report. How can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not too sure what the problem is here.

Just paste your `MDX` into the `Dataset` in `SSRS`

Add a `matrix` to your report.

Select some of the available fields from the `dataset` for the report.

Rename columns in your `matrix`

---

**Edit**

I just copied this into my `dataset` and all columns appeared:

```
SELECT 
  NON EMPTY 
    {[Measures].[Internet Order Count]} ON COLUMNS
 ,NON EMPTY 
    {[Product].[Product Categories].[Category].ALLMEMBERS}
  DIMENSION PROPERTIES 
    MEMBER_CAPTION
   ,MEMBER_UNIQUE_NAME
   ON ROWS
FROM [Adventure Works]
```

Also when I use the wizard to build the query all columns appear ok

Comment: Thank you for your answer! The problem is that the two columns without an header isn't available as fields from the dataset, as far as I can tell.

Comment: @bjornasm - in some cases this happens - try building the query using the drag and drop functionality in the dataset wizard. Also try specifically adding in the `DIMENSION PROPERTIES` as in the above query I've added to answer.